# Creating interaction terms in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, kernel, interaction

I'm trying to create interaction terms in a dataset. Is there another (simpler) way of creating interaction terms of columns in a dataset? For example, creating interaction terms in combinations of columns 4:98 and 98:106. I tried looping over the columns using numpy arrays, but with the following code, the kernel keeps dying.

```
col1 = df.columns[4:98] #94 columns 
col2 = df.columns[98:106] #8 columns
var1_np = df_np[:, 4:98]
var2_np = df_np[:, 98:106]
for i in range(94):
    for j in range(8):
        name = col1[i] +"*" + col2[j]
        df[name] = var1_np[:,i]*var2_np[:,j]
```

Here, df is the dataframe and df_np is df in NumPy array.

Comment: Did you check the memory usage on your machine during the execution of this code?  We don't know how may rows there are in your dataframe, but given the number of new columns you are creating, memory could be an issue.  You may want to try testing your code on a smaller number of columns. You could also try creating a numpy array with interaction terms and then converting the whole array into a new dataframe at once, as that will be a less expensive operation.

Comment: Also, scikit-learn's [PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) is often used to generate interaction terms.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) that is roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. Then, use `join` to create the new column name with the `product` result. After that, use Pandas [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) to return the product of two columns over the axis one (along the columns).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

#setup
np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.random.rand(5, 10).round(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = [f'col_{c}' for c in range(0,10)]
print(df)

#code
col1 = df.columns[3:5]
col2 = df.columns[5:8]

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i in product(col1, col2):
    name = "*".join(i)
    df_new[name] = df[list(i)].prod(axis=1)

print(df_new)
```

Output from *df*

```py
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7  col_8  col_9
0   0.93   0.32   0.18   0.20   0.57   0.60   0.96   0.65   0.75   0.65
1   0.75   0.96   0.01   0.11   0.30   0.66   0.81   0.87   0.96   0.72
2   0.64   0.72   0.47   0.33   0.44   0.73   0.99   0.68   0.79   0.17
3   0.03   0.80   0.90   0.02   0.49   0.53   0.60   0.05   0.90   0.73
4   0.82   0.50   0.81   0.10   0.22   0.26   0.47   0.46   0.71   0.18
```

Output from *df_new*

```py
   col_3*col_5  col_3*col_6  col_3*col_7  col_4*col_5  col_4*col_6  col_4*col_7
0       0.1200       0.1920       0.1300       0.3420       0.5472       0.3705
1       0.0726       0.0891       0.0957       0.1980       0.2430       0.2610
2       0.2409       0.3267       0.2244       0.3212       0.4356       0.2992
3       0.0106       0.0120       0.0010       0.2597       0.2940       0.0245
4       0.0260       0.0470       0.0460       0.0572       0.1034       0.1012
```